# Windows Device doesn't boot on Galileo

Tags: intel-galileo, windowsondevices

Some days ago I received my "Windows On Devices Kit" with one Galileo Gen 1 (thanks MS). But until now I couldn´t see my Galileo on the GalileoWatcher.

I already tried a lot of things, but nothing works.

Until now, the things that I have sure that is working are:

- Galileo is working very well: I installed Arduino IDE 1.5.3 from Intel and deploy a "blinking test" on device and it's working;
- Galileo is working with the recommended firmware 1.0.2;
- SD Card is working: I formated the Card and installed the Linux version from Intel and it worked;
- Boot from SD Card is working: I put the SD card on Galileo and restarted and the Linux start to work;
- I downloaded the last version of windows for devices from http://connect.microsoft.com/windowsembeddedIoT/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=54159 and deployed on the SD Card. After this I tried to boot Galileo and it not worked;

Someone have any idea about what is wrong in my Setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try formatting your sd card as MBR, instead of GPT

Answer (score 0):

Mine didn't connect either on the first boot. I had everything plugged in, power, Ethernet to my network switch, usb to my computer, clicked the reboot micro switch and it came up in the Galileo board watcher. After that it went as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes GalileoWatcher app doesn't work, you must connect your Galileo board and the computer to the same network and the network must have DHCP enabled in order to give an IP to the Galileo board.

If after that GalileoWatcher doesn't find your board use an IP scanner software to detect the address of your board.